# Cómo crear una función dinámica para crear Querys de inserción a una BD en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

La idea es crear una función que me permita crear querys  `Insert into...`
para multiples tablas, sin necesidad de tener que crear una función para cada tabla, dado que el número de columnas varía.

Lo que quiero evitar es crear una cadena tipo

```
INSERT INTO tabla1 (columna1, columna2, columna3) VALUES ('dato1', 'dato2', 'dato3');
```

para cada una de las tablas, simplemente pasarle el array con los datos:

```
$datos = [
  "columna1" => "Dato 1",
  "columna2" => "Dato 2",
  "columna3" => "Dato 3"
];
```

y que la misma función cree la cadena de manera dinámica, dependiendo del número de datos.

Answer (score 1):

No hace falta el doble `foreach`, basta con usar [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php), [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php) e [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php).

Por ejemplo:

```php
<?php
function getInsertStatement($data, $tableName) {
    if(!count($data)) {
        return '';
    }
    $columnNames = implode(",",array_keys($data));
    $values = implode("','", array_values($data));
    return "INSERT INTO ".$tableName." (".$columnNames.")"." VALUES ('".$values."');";
}

$datosPrueba1 = [
  "columna1" => "Dato 1",
  "columna2" => "Dato 2",
  "columna3" => "Dato 3",
  "columna4" => "Dato 4"
];

$datosPrueba2 = [
  "columna1" => "Dato 1",
  "columna2" => "Dato 2",
  "columna3" => "Dato 3",
  "columna4" => "Dato 4",
  "columna5" => "Dato 5",
  "columna6" => "Dato 6",
  "columna7" => "Dato 7",
  "columna8" => "Dato 8"
];

$datosPrueba3 = [];

echo getInsertStatement($datosPrueba1, "testTable");
echo '<br>';
echo getInsertStatement($datosPrueba2, "testTable");
echo '<br>';
echo getInsertStatement($datosPrueba3, "testTable");
```

Lo cual produce lo siguiente:

```sql
INSERT INTO testTable 
 (columna1,columna2,columna3,columna4) VALUES ('Dato 1','Dato 2','Dato 3','Dato 4');
INSERT INTO testTable 
 (columna1,columna2,columna3,columna4,columna5,columna6,columna7,columna8) VALUES ('Dato 1','Dato 2','Dato 3','Dato 4','Dato 5','Dato 6','Dato 7','Dato 8');
```

Como se aprecia, no importa el tamaño del Array, la sentencia *INSERT* es creada de acuerdo a los datos asociativos del mismo. Cabe destacar que si el Array no tiene datos, se devuelve una cadena vacía.

Tambien hay que acotar que el separador usado para los valores a insertar es `','`,

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que soluciona esto es crear la función, y dentro de la función hacer 2 foreach que iteren sobre el arreglo para que se puedan crear 2 cadenas, una para las columnas y otra para los datos:

```
//creamos la función y pedimos como parámetro el array y la tabla a la que se van a insertar los datos
function insertar($datos, $tabla)
{
  //en esta cadena se van a guardar los datos a insertar
  $datoInsertar = "";
  //en esta otra se guardan las columnas de la tabla
  $column = "";
  //contamos el número de datos
  $numItems = count($datos);
  //un contador auxiliar para determinar el último dato del arreglo
  $i = 0;

  foreach ($datos as $dato => $value) {
   /*aquí el $value nos sirve para obtener el Key del arreglo    
     (que debería ser el nombre de la columna */

   //Verificamos si el dato es el ultimo del arreglo, si no lo es, ponemos una coma después
    if (++$i !== $numItems) {
      $column .= $dato. ", ";
    } else {
     //en caso de que sea el último, no se agrega la coma
      $column .= $dato;
    }
  }

  //reiniciamos el contador
  $i = 0;

  //y repetimos lo mismo para las cadenas
  foreach ($datos as $d) {
    if (++$i !== $numItems) {
      //lo único diferente es que se agregan comillas para los datos
      $datoInsertar .= "'" . $d . "', ";
    } else {
      $datoInsertar .= "'" . $d . "'";
    }
  }
  //al final creamos la cadena juntando los strings
  $queryFinal = "INSERT INTO $tabla ( $column ) VALUES ($datoInsertar);";

return $queryFinal;
}
```

Ahora, para corroborar que todo funcione, creamos 2 arreglos y 2 cadenas con el nombre de la tabla, y mandamos a llamar la función 2 veces.

```
$datosPrueba1 = [
  "columna1" => "Dato 1",
  "columna2" => "Dato 2",
  "columna3" => "Dato 3",
  "columna4" => "Dato 4"
];

$datosPrueba2 = [
  "columna1" => "Dato 1",
  "columna2" => "Dato 2",
  "columna3" => "Dato 3",
  "columna4" => "Dato 4",
  "columna5" => "Dato 5",
  "columna6" => "Dato 6",
  "columna7" => "Dato 7",
  "columna8" => "Dato 8"
];

$tabla1 = "tabla1";
$tabla2 = "tabla2";


echo ins($datosPrueba1, $tabla1);
echo "<br>";
echo ins($datosPrueba2, $tabla2);
```

Eso nos debería dar como resultado lo siguiente

```
INSERT INTO tabla1 ( columna1, columna2, columna3, columna4 ) VALUES ('Dato 1', 'Dato 2', 'Dato 3', 'Dato 4');
INSERT INTO tabla2 ( columna1, columna2, columna3, columna4, columna5, columna6, columna7, columna8 ) VALUES ('Dato 1', 'Dato 2', 'Dato 3', 'Dato 4', 'Dato 5', 'Dato 6', 'Dato 7', 'Dato 8');
```

Espero que les ayude! un saludo a todos!